# Invalid File Content When trying to read file in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read a file in C. First I am calculating the lines in the file:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("No file specified");
    exit(1);
  }

  FILE* pFile;
  char currentCharacter;
  int lines = 1;

  pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  for (currentCharacter = getc(pFile); currentCharacter != EOF; currentCharacter = getc(pFile))
  {
    if (currentCharacter == '\n') lines++;
  }

  ...
}
```

After calculating the lines in the file, I tried reading one by one, like this:

```c
char currentLine[255];

for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
{
  fgets(currentLine, 255, pFile);

  printf("%s\n", currentLine);
}

fclose(pFile);
```

But everytime I run it, I am getting this output:

```bash
²a
```

When I try to remove the for loop and place `fgets()` and `printf()` outside, it prints **NOTHING**

If you are wondering, here is the content of the file I am trying to read:

test.txt

```
test1
test2
test3
```

NOTE: The file is being successfully opened as it is counting the lines correctly.

Comment: Hint: after counting the number of lines, where is the next place in the file you'll read from?

Comment: `getchar` returns an int.  If you write the value to a char and compare that to EOF, you will not get reliable results.  Change the type of currrentCharacter to `int`.  (In C, `'a'` is an int, not a char)

Comment: You never account for the files being empty. Of non-existent (you never check if `fopen` fails or not). And you don't check if `fgets` fails, which will leave the buffer with *indeterminate* contents.

Comment: Attempting to precompute the size of a file is always a bad idea.  Unless your program's sole purpose is to report the size of the file, you should (almost) never do this.  Read data until there is no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, no need to count the lines. Just stop when there is nothing more to read. That is, when fgets returns NULL.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("No file specified");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE* pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("File is not found");
        exit(1);
    }

    char currentLine[256];

    while(fgets(currentLine, 256, pFile))
    {
        printf("%s", currentLine);
    }

    return 0;
}
```